# Jquery value of dropdown not selected

Tags: jquery

I have populated a dropdown list with values using an array. But whenever I get the selected value from the dropdown, it is not showing or doing the corresponding action.My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cat").on('click', function () {
        var data = {
            '1': 'Mock 1',
            '2': 'Mock 2',
            '3': 'Mock 3',
            '4': 'Mock4',
            '5': 'Mock5'
        }

        var s = $('<select id="c" />');

        for(var val in data) {
            $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
        }

        s.appendTo('#f'); // or wherever it should be
    });
    </script>
   <script>

    var m=$( "#c option:selected" ).text();
    alert(m);
    if(m=="Mock 1") {
        var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_2_question.pdf";
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    if(m=="Mock 2") {
        var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_3_question.pdf";
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    if(m=="Mock 3") {
        var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_4_question.pdf";
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    if(m=="Mock4") {
        var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_5_question.pdf";
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
  </script>
```

I have also tried putting this block under the click event but the moment it sees that Mock1 is selected it redirects to the other page so the user wont be able to select other options. Please help me in correcting the code.

Comment: Have you tried using the change event instead of the click event?  And you other block should be inside the event code.

Comment: it is automatically selecting first option. how to tweak the code so that we can select other options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to wrap in $(document).ready and move your $("#cat").on call...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = {
        '1': 'Mock 1',
        '2': 'Mock 2',
        '3': 'Mock 3',
        '4': 'Mock4',
        '5': 'Mock5'
    }

    var s = $('<select id="c" />');

    for(var val in data) {
        $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
    }

    s.appendTo('#f'); // or wherever it should be
    $("#cat").on('click', function () {
        var m=$( "#c option:selected" ).text();
        alert(m);
        if(m=="Mock 1") {
            var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_2_question.pdf";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        }
        else if(m=="Mock 2") {
            var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_3_question.pdf";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        }
        else if(m=="Mock 3") {
            var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_4_question.pdf";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        }
        else if(m=="Mock4") {
            var url = "http://www.careerlauncher.com/sis/mba/mock_5_question.pdf";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The code is not working. I want to fire the dropdown when i click the button  with id cat

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there was another button.  I had modified to work off a change of the list.  I have modified the example and verified functionality.